# Unable to change polyline segment to circular arc

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a poly line connected by a variety of vertices. I think the polyline is a straight line rather than a proper arc between each vertex. I was trying to follow the instructions [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/changing-a-segment-to-straight-or-curved.htm) but the cursor never came up to select the individual segment. I even split the polyline at the vertex prior to the line segment I wanted to alter, but I find no option to "Change Segment".

Is there another way to do this? I have ArcGIS10.3 (specifically the ArcMap application).

Comment: What format is your data in? Shapefiles do not support ICurve segments and automatically *stroke* curves generated (very short straight line segments approximating your curve).

Comment: @MichaelStimson Not sure what you mean by format. But to test my theory, I took the vertices of the line, built a new table and then used the _XY to Line_ tool which allowed me to specify the coordinate system and line type. As expected, the line conformed properly with a curve. Unlike the _Points to Line_ tool which drew straight connections to each vertex.

Comment: By format I mean is it shapefile, geodatabase feature class, coverage etc.. not all formats support curves. Although you can create a curve in a shapefile by drawing *as soon as you save it will be stroked to a line*, I learned that one the *hard* way.. days of work plotting nice curves then, when I went back to check my work, all of the curves were short straight sections approximating a curve.